# Implementing a genetic algorithm to solve the Diophantine Equation

Tags: c++, beginner, algorithm

I am trying to implement a genetic algorithm to solve (Diophantine Equation).

For instance, a + 2b + 3c + 4d = 90 where a, b, c, d are positive integers.

After reading some books and following tutorials, I finally wrote this code, but as I am new to programming and GA, I don't know if this is a good implementation.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

#define variable 4
#define chromoSize 100000
float total = 0;
struct Equation
{
int eq[variable];
float ev;
float fit;
float p;
};


void init_chrom(vector<Equation> &Original, vector<Equation> &Temp)
{
  for(int i=0; i<chromoSize; i++)
    {
       Equation e;
      for(int j=0; j<variable; j++)
       {
         e.eq[j] = rand() % 30;
         e.fit = 0;
       }

      Original.push_back(e);
   }

      Temp.resize(chromoSize);
}

void calc_fit(vector<Equation> &orginalCh)
{
    for(int i=0; i<chromoSize; i++)
     {

       int j = 0;
       orginalCh[i].ev = abs((orginalCh[i].eq[j] + 2*orginalCh[i].eq[j+1] +
       3*orginalCh[i].eq[j+2] + 4*orginalCh[i].eq[j+3]) - 10);

    }
}

void select_fit(vector<Equation> &orginalCh)
{
     for(int i=0; i<chromoSize; i++)
      {
         orginalCh[i].fit = 1 /( 1 + orginalCh[i].ev);
         total += orginalCh[i].fit;
      }

   float pro = 0;
   for(int i=0; i<chromoSize; i++)
    {
       pro += orginalCh[i].fit / total;
       orginalCh[i].p = pro;
    }

}

void _copy(vector<Equation> &p1, vector<Equation> &p2, int s)
{
   for(int i=0; i<s; i++)
     {
        for(int j=0; j<variable; j++)
            p2[i].eq[j] = p1[i].eq[j];

            p2[i].fit = p1[i].fit;
     }
}

void mutate(vector<Equation> &parent2, int i)
{
     int size = variable;
     int index1 = rand() % size;
     int index2 = rand() % size;
     int j = rand() % chromoSize;

    parent2[i].eq[index1] = parent2[j].eq[index2];


}
void mate(vector<Equation> &parent1, vector<Equation> &parent2)
{

     int sub, p1, p2, tSsize = variable;

    _copy(parent1, parent2, chromoSize);

    for(int i=0; i<chromoSize; i++)
      {
        p1 = rand() % chromoSize;
        p2 = rand() % chromoSize;
        sub = rand() % tSsize;

       for(int j=sub; j<variable; j++)
          parent2[p2].eq[j] = parent1[p1].eq[j];

       if(parent2[i].ev > 0.1f)
            mutate(parent2, i);
     }


 }

bool sort_fitness(Equation x, Equation y)
{
   return(x.fit > y.fit);
}
void _sort(vector<Equation> &orginalCh)
{
    sort(orginalCh.begin(),orginalCh.end(),sort_fitness);
}
void swap(vector<Equation> *&parent1, vector<Equation> *&parent2)
{
     vector<Equation> *temp = parent1;
     parent1 = parent2;
     parent2 = temp;
}
void print(vector<Equation> &originalCh)
{
    for(int i=0; i<variable; i++)
     {
       cout<<originalCh[0].eq[i]<<", ";
     }

     cout<<" "<<originalCh[0].ev<<" "<<originalCh[0].fit;
     cout<<endl;
}

int main()
{
     srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));

     vector<Equation> chromO, chromT;
     vector<Equation> *originalCh, *bufferCh;
     init_chrom(chromO, chromT);

    originalCh = &chromO;
    bufferCh = &chromT;

    for(int i=0; i<2000; i++)
       {
        calc_fit(*originalCh);
        select_fit(*originalCh);
        _sort(*originalCh);
        print(*originalCh);

        if((*originalCh)[0].fit == 1) break;

        mate(*originalCh,*bufferCh);
        swap(*originalCh, *bufferCh);

      }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
 }
```

The code will output something like this:

```
21, 22, 7, 1,  0 1
```

The first four numbers are the values of (a,b,c,d) and the fifth number is the evaluation and the last number is the fitness.

**UPDATE**

After taking @glampert post into consideration and reading more about what he suggested, this is an updated version of the above code.

**GeneticAlgorithm.h**

```
#include <vector>
#include <random>

//the variables in the equation, which represnts the (a,b,c,d)
const int VARIABLES = 4;
//the size of chromosoms population
const int CHROMO_SIZE = 10000;

class GA
{

 public:
    struct Equation
    {
        int equation[VARIABLES];
        float evaluation;
        float fit;
        float probability;
    };

 public:
    GA();
    //initialize the chromosoms
    void initChromos(std::vector<Equation> &original, std::vector<Equation> &temp);

    //calculate the fitness of chromosoms
    void calcFitness(std::vector<Equation> &orginalCh);

    //select the fit ones
    void selectFitness(std::vector<Equation> &orginalCh);

    //copy from parent one to parent two
    void copyFromP1toP2(std::vector<Equation> &parent1, 
                        std::vector<Equation> &parent2, int size);

    //mutate the chromosoms and select two chromosoms to mate
    void mutate(std::vector<Equation> &parent2, int i);
    void mate(std::vector<Equation> &parent1, std::vector<Equation> &parent2);

    //sort chromosoms by fitness
    bool static sortFitness(Equation x, Equation y);
    void sortByFitness(std::vector<Equation> &orginalCh);

    //swap parent one and parent two for the next generation
    void swap(std::vector<Equation> *&parent1, std::vector<Equation> *&parent2);

    //print the best fit of every generation
    void print(std::vector<Equation> &originalCh);

    //generate random number
    int randGenerate(int start, int end);

 public:
    std::default_random_engine dRandom;

 private:
    float total;

};
```

**Implementation.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include<random>

#include "GeneticAlgorithm.h"

GA::GA(): total(0),dRandom()
{
}

void GA::initChromos(std::vector<Equation> &original, std::vector<Equation>  &temp)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < CHROMO_SIZE; i++)
      {
          GA::Equation e;
          for(int j = 0; j < VARIABLES; j++)
            {
               int randNum = randGenerate(0,40);
               e.equation[j]= randNum;
               e.fit = 0;
             }

            original.push_back(e);
       }

       temp.resize(CHROMO_SIZE);
 }

void GA::calcFitness(std::vector<Equation> &orginalCh)
 {
      for(int i = 0; i < CHROMO_SIZE; i++)
        {

             int j = 0;
             orginalCh[i].evaluation = (float)abs((orginalCh[i].equation[j] + 2 *  orginalCh[i].equation[ j + 1 ] 
                                    + 3 * orginalCh[i].equation[ j + 2 ] + 4 * orginalCh[i].equation[ j + 3 ]) - 4 );

        }
 }

void GA::selectFitness(std::vector<Equation> &orginalCh)
 {
        for(int i = 0; i < CHROMO_SIZE; i++)
           {
               orginalCh[i].fit = 1 / ( 1 + orginalCh[i].evaluation);
               total += orginalCh[i].fit;
            }

         float pro = 0;
         for(int i = 0; i < CHROMO_SIZE; i++)
          {
               pro += orginalCh[i].fit / total;
               orginalCh[i].probability = pro;
          }

 }

void GA::copyFromP1toP2(std::vector<Equation> &p1, std::vector<Equation> &p2, int s)
 {
        for(int i = 0; i < s; i++)
           {
               for(int j = 0; j < VARIABLES; j++)
                 {
                     p2[i].equation[j] = p1[i].equation[j];
                 }

               p2[i].fit = p1[i].fit;
           }
 }

void GA::mutate(std::vector<Equation> &parent2, int i)
 {

      int index1 = randGenerate(0, VARIABLES - 1);
      int index2 = randGenerate(0, VARIABLES - 1);

      int j = randGenerate(0, CHROMO_SIZE - 1);


      parent2[i].equation[index1] = parent2[j].equation[index2];


  }

void GA::mate(std::vector<Equation> &parent1, std::vector<Equation> &parent2)
 {

       int sub, p1, p2, p3, tSsize = VARIABLES;

       copyFromP1toP2(parent1, parent2, CHROMO_SIZE);

       for(int i = 0; i < CHROMO_SIZE; i++)
          {
               p1 = randGenerate(0, CHROMO_SIZE - 1);
               p2 = randGenerate(0, CHROMO_SIZE - 1);;
               p3 = randGenerate(0, CHROMO_SIZE - 1);
               sub = randGenerate(0, VARIABLES - 1);

               for(int j=sub; j<VARIABLES; j++)
                 {
                       parent2[p2].equation[j] = abs(parent1[p1].equation[j] - parent1[p3].equation[j]);
                 }

           if(parent2[i].evaluation > 0.5f)
                 mutate(parent2, i);
          }


 }

bool GA::sortFitness(Equation x, Equation y)
 {
        return(x.fit > y.fit);
 }

void GA::sortByFitness(std::vector<Equation> &orginalCh)
 {
        std::sort(orginalCh.begin(),orginalCh.end(),&GA::sortFitness);
 }

void GA::swap(std::vector<GA::Equation> *&parent1, std::vector<GA::Equation> *&parent2)
 {
       std::vector<GA::Equation> *temp = parent1;
       parent1 = parent2;
       parent2 = temp;
 }  

void GA::print(std::vector<Equation> &originalCh)
 {
      for(int i=0; i<VARIABLES; i++)
         {
            std::cout<< originalCh[0].equation[i] << ", ";
         }

        std::cout  << " fitness = " << originalCh[0].fit;
        std::cout<< std::endl;
  }

 int GA::randGenerate(int start, int end)
  {
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> genenNum(start, end - 1);

        return genenNum(dRandom);
  }

int main()
 {

        GA ga;
        std::vector<GA::Equation> chromO, chromT;
        std::vector<GA::Equation> *originalCh, *bufferCh;

        ga.initChromos(chromO, chromT);

        originalCh = &chromO;
        bufferCh = &chromT;

        for(int i=0; i<2000; i++)
             {
                    ga.calcFitness(*originalCh);
                    ga.selectFitness(*originalCh);
                    ga.sortByFitness(*originalCh);
                    ga.print(*originalCh);

                    if((*originalCh)[0].fit == 1) break;

                    ga.mate(*originalCh,*bufferCh);
                    ga.swap(*&originalCh, *&bufferCh);

             }

      std::cin.get();

      return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so first of all, your code is far from being C++. It is more like C using some C++ features, such as `std::vector`. I'm not going to refactor all of your code into a class, instead, this is an exercise for you: Take all those loose functions and data and put them in a C++ class. This is one possible interface you can start with:

```
class GeneticAlgorithm 
{
public:

    void initChromosomes(vector<Equation> &Original, vector<Equation> &Temp);
    void calcFitness(vector<Equation> &orginalCh);
    void selectFit(vector<Equation> &orginalCh);
    void mutate(vector<Equation> &parent2, int i);
    void mate(vector<Equation> &parent1, vector<Equation> &parent2);
    void print(const vector<Equation> &originalCh)

private:

    // Internal helper methods and data.
    // ...
};
```

---

### Other style and code quality issues:

**Names should not start with `_`!**

Names starting with an underscore `_` are [reserved for the C++ implementation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword), so they are a no-no. This is wrong:

```
void _sort(vector<Equation> &orginalCh)
{
    sort(orginalCh.begin(), orginalCh.end(), sort_fitness);
}
```

I see that you've defined `_sort` as a shorthand for the `std::sort` algorithm. This is OK, but give the function another name. E.g.: `sortByFitness()` which is also a lot more meaningful.

**`#define` for constants, not recommended:**

Macros (AKA `defines`) are an inherited C feature that has quite a few drawbacks and problems. One of the most problematic ones is that they don't respect scope. Once you declare a macro, it is visible everywhere. This makes them a very poor choice for declaring constants. C++ offers much better ways. The constants you've defined with macros should be instead defined with `const int` or even better `constexpr int` if your compiler has C++11 support. But also, the names you gave to the variables are not optimal. Constants are by convention named differently. One common naming convention for constants it using `ALL_CAPS`. So I suggest you redeclare:

```
constexpr int VARIABLE = 4;
constexpr int CHROMO_SIZE = 100000;
```

Also note that now the constants are strongly typed (`int`), which is a nice thing since the compiler can now warn you about unwanted conversions.

**Using namespace std?**

You have a `using namespace std;` at the beginning of the file. This is generally not a good idea, since it defeats the purpose of a namespace, which is allowing identical names to coexist without clashes. I recommend that you remove any `using namespace std;` occurrences and call the library functions an types by their fully qualified names, E.g.: `std::vector`, `std::sort`, `std::copy`, etc.

**`rand()`:**

C++11 has a brand new (and awesome!) [random number library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). If your compiler supports C++11, you should definitely check it out and replace the old and unreliable `rand()` that you currently use.

**Use of `system("pause")`:**

This was noted by @Edward in a comment below, I forgot to mention it in my first iteration, so thanks for the reminder:

> `system("pause")` is a non-portable security nightmare that will run any local program named "pause". It might just pause, or it might format your hard drive. Please use something like `std::cin.get()` instead.

**Poor spacing and indentation:**

Your code is poorly indented and spaced on some places, also, you are not consistent with your spacing. Take these lines for example:

```
orginalCh[i].ev = abs((orginalCh[i].eq[j] + 2*orginalCh[i].eq[j+1] +
3*orginalCh[i].eq[j+2] + 4*orginalCh[i].eq[j+3]) - 10);
```

The above are tightly packed (which I find pretty hard to read, BTW). While this is more spaced:

```
orginalCh[i].fit = 1 /( 1 + orginalCh[i].ev);
```

All the code you've posted suffers from indenting problems, I don't know if this problem occurred when you posted it here or if it is like that in your project, but the guideline stays: Be very consistent with spacing and indenting. A well formatted code will be way easier for the reader to "parse".

**What is the expected behavior here?**

```
void _copy(vector<Equation> &p1, vector<Equation> &p2, int s)
{
   for(int i=0; i<s; i++)
   {
        for(int j=0; j<variable; j++)
           p2[i].eq[j] = p1[i].eq[j];

           p2[i].fit = p1[i].fit;
    }
}
```

This function is an example of an issue I frequently see in code. The last statement line, `p2[i].fit = p1[i].fit;`, is it meant to belong to last `for()`? The way it is indented, it leads the reader to believe so. A more careful look will reveal that it belongs to the first loop, being executed only `s` times (which is likely to be the correct). Is that the intended behavior, or did you actually mean this?

```
for(int i=0; i<s; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<variable; j++)
    {
        p2[i].eq[j] = p1[i].eq[j];
        p2[i].fit = p1[i].fit;
    }
}
```

Or this?

```
for(int i=0; i<s; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<variable; j++)
    {
        p2[i].eq[j] = p1[i].eq[j];
    }
    p2[i].fit = p1[i].fit;
}
```

This guideline is worth more than what most people think: Always enclose `if, while, for` and other control flow statements with `{}` braces, even if they are single line statements.

**Miscellaneous:**

Don't bunch up functions like you did here. Put a blank line between each.

```
bool sort_fitness(Equation x, Equation y)
{
   return(x.fit > y.fit);
}
void _sort(vector<Equation> &orginalCh)
{
    sort(orginalCh.begin(),orginalCh.end(),sort_fitness);
}
void swap(vector<Equation> *&parent1, vector<Equation> *&parent2)
{
     vector<Equation> *temp = parent1;
     parent1 = parent2;
     parent2 = temp;
}
```

Better:

```
bool sort_fitness(Equation x, Equation y)
{
   return(x.fit > y.fit);
}

void _sort(vector<Equation> &orginalCh)
{
    sort(orginalCh.begin(),orginalCh.end(),sort_fitness);
}

void swap(vector<Equation> *&parent1, vector<Equation> *&parent2)
{
     vector<Equation> *temp = parent1;
     parent1 = parent2;
     parent2 = temp;
}
```

---

Falls into the previous spacing/indenting tip, but:

```
cout<<" "<<originalCh[0].ev<<" "<<originalCh[0].fit;
```

In my opinion is more readable with some spacing between the `<<` operators:

```
std::cout << " " << originalCh[0].ev << " " << originalCh[0].fit;
```

---

Mind your variable naming convention. Consistency it very important, regardless of the style you choose, once you choose one, you must be consistent with it.

You have some parameter variables names with an upper-case first letter, like `Original` and `Temp` in here:

```
void init_chrom(vector<Equation> &Original, vector<Equation> &Temp)
```

Whereas in here

```
void calc_fit(vector<Equation> &orginalCh)
```

You've used a lower-case letter for `orginalCh`. Variable names are usually declared like `orginalCh`, that is, first letter lower-case and each new word starting with an upper-case. This style is sometimes called "[camel-case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)" or "camel-back". Another popular naming convention for function parameter variables in the "[snake-case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case)", like this: `orginal_char`, Choose one and stick with it throughout your code.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Did you run the program? if you did, do you have any command about that.

Comment: No, impossible to run. The code you've posted is missing some variables, as was commented by @Edward, above. You should edit that when you can.

Comment: Alright, here is the complete code [link](http://pastebin.com/KM267DE7)

Comment: Also `system("pause")` is a non-portable security nightmare that will run any local program named "pause." It might just pause, or it might format your hard drive.  Please use something like `std::cin.get()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Good job! Your code has improved a lot, congrats! But there is still room for more improvement, so I'll now give you a review on the newly edited code.

**Redundant `#include`s:**

`GeneticAlgorithm.h` is already including `<vector>` and `<random>`, so you don't need to include them again in the `.cpp`; This only slows down the compilation.

**Missing an include guard in the header file:**

If you ever plan on including `GeneticAlgorithm.h` on any other `.cpp` file, you are going to need an [include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) or a [`#pragma once`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once) directive in that header file.

**Move related constants into the class:**

The `const`s are way better than the previous `#define`s, but why not place them inside the `GA` class? These constants are only used inside the class, so encapsulate them in there. You will have to mark them `static`.

```
class GA
{
private:
    //the variables in the equation, which represnts the (a,b,c,d)
    static const int VARIABLES = 4;
    //the size of chromosoms population
    static const int CHROMO_SIZE = 10000;
```

Make them private if they are not needed outside. A good rule of thumb is to avoid exposing implementation details and keeping interfaces short.

**Use an alias or `typedef` where appropriate:**

These `std::vector<GA::Equation>` are the GA chromosomes, I believe (I wrote some GA code a while back, but can't remember much about the data structures...). You can make your code semantically nicer by giving these vectors an alias. This adds no type safety, but can make the code a lot clearer. I like the new C++11 `using` alias:

```
using Chromosomes = std::vector<GA::Equation>;
```

But if your compiler doesn't understand it, you can fallback to a "classic" `typedef`:

```
typedef std::vector<GA::Equation> Chromosomes;
```

Then replace the `std::vector<GA::Equation>` with `Chromosomes`.

**Encapsulate more?**

Currently, the `GA` class has very few state and you pass a lot of vectors to the class methods. Isn't it a better design to encapsulate everything inside the `GA`? This could simplify the interface a lot.

Take the variables you have declared in `main()` and make them `GA` members. Then define a single public function the user of `GA` has to call. Something similar to:

```
void GA::simulate(int numIterations)
{
        initChromos();
        for (int i = 0; i < numIterations; i++)
        {
            calcFitness();
            selectFitness();
            sortByFitness();
            print();
            if (originalChild[0].fit == 1) 
            {
                break;
            }
            mate();
      }
}
```

Then all `main()` would have to do is:

```
int main()
{
    GA ga;
    ga.simulate(2000);
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

**Try our new C++11 lambdas!**

You can use a [lambda function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) for your sort predicate in `GA::sortByFitness()`, it is a very nice new language feature and it should be used.

```
void GA::sortByFitness(std::vector<Equation> &orginalCh)
{
    std::sort(orginalCh.begin(), orginalCh.end(), 
         [](const Equation & x, const Equation & y) -> bool { return (x.fit > y.fit); }
    );
}
```

**Last thing:**

```
void GA::copyFromP1toP2(std::vector<Equation> &p1, std::vector<Equation> &p2, int s)
```

The `s` parameter, besides being a very poor variable name, is really not necessary, since, in the call site, you are passing a constant to the function:

```
copyFromP1toP2(parent1, parent2, CHROMO_SIZE);
```

Just remove that parameter and replace it by `CHROMO_SIZE`.